# What is Google Apps?

Tags: google-apps

What is google apps and why are so many startup companies using it?

Comment: "not programming related"?  You realize Google Apps is a platform for writing apps in Python right?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, nominating for reopen.

Comment: No, Google Apps is a hosted web app service - Google App Engine is the hosting service for distributed Python apps.

Comment: I was asking because I knew little about google apps at the time and wanted to learn more about it since you can use python with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One useful feature of Google apps is that it allows you to use the gmail interface to host email on google's servers for your own domain.  So you can send/recieve email with an @example.com address (if your startup was called example.com).

Answer (score 6):

[Google Apps](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) is a collection of business software components delivered as a service, saving you from having to install Exchange, Office and the usual business stuff.  Plus Google Apps allows people to write their own apps and install them on Google's servers.  A lot of companies use Google Apps for email and calendering instead of Exchange these days.  It saves costs.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike many apps, the Google Business Apps are intuitive.  Calendars, email, file sharing, contacts, and more are simple to use and will work virtually on any internet connected device.

basic benefits of google apps are - 
1. It is Cost Efficient - For only $5 a month, you will receive email addresses for your team with your company's name, 30 GB storage you can use for file storage and sharing, online calendars, and the ability to easily create online spreadsheets, slides, text documents, and more. All these great features including admin controls and security from a name you can trust. If you prepay for a year you will actually save $10.

2. Security - The company is FISMA-Moderate level certified -- this is the same level of certification for the internal email usage within the United State's government. Google is also capable of supporting HIPAA compliance. Google is trusted by millions to virtually secure their email from any threats through routinely checking emails before downloading a document for any threats of viruses, pshing emails, malware and more.
3. User friendly and intutive interface.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps are...
“A set of intelligent apps including Gmail, Docs, Drive, and Calendar to connect the people in your company, no matter where in the world they are.”
Source:  https://gsuite.google.com/together/

**Examples**:  Google Calendar, Google Drive, Google Hangouts, Google Slides, Google Spreadsheets - those are all [web-based applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) ("apps").

G Suite is the name given by Google for their collection of applications.  Formerly named “Google Apps for Work” and “Google Apps for Your Domain”, G Suite is resource implemented by I.T. Administrators, to enable access to Google Apps, through a domain (and their aliases).

**For Example**:  Rather than using your standard Gmail address (*username*@gmail.com), users in a business or organization would login to access those web-apps using an email address with their own domain, like (*username*@example.com).

The interface is the same as for standard Google Account holders, yet G Suite admins have the ability to add some branding, and control features - through the G Suite Admin Console.

I'm going to stop here before this post starts to resemble a pitch - let's just say that I really enjoy the fact that my workplace has implemented G Suite for our organization - it has made my duties, that much easier!